# How to take a screenshot at every mouse click

Tags: window-manager

How can I make a window manager take a screenshot at every mouse click? Preferably taking a screenshot first, then pass the mouse click event to the underlying window.

In Gnome, if I press <kbd>prt sc</kbd> a screenshot will be taken and saved without question. That's the effect I want for every mouse click. Also, I probably can't use Gnome since it's a virtual X session which Gnome/Unity isn't designed for.

I will accept solutions for using any window manager, be it twm, fvwm or i3 or anything.

Comment: `gnome-screenshot` should work irrespective of the window manager. At least it does with Openbox.

Comment: @DKBose do you mean that in Openbox if you press <kbd>prt sc</kbd> it will run gnome-screenshot? Is it by default? If so I can use it to produce a serial of snapshots by pressing that key every time before I click a mouse button.

Comment: Lubuntu uses `scrot` in a similar way and it uses the Openbox window manager, Anyway, it will also take a screenshot that way by pressing the PrintScreen key and store it in a file with a time string in the name. This file will go to your home directory in Lubuntu (while the screenshot goes to `~/Pictures` in standard Ubuntu). By the way, Ubuntu 18.04.x uses gnome, so it should work for you too.

Comment: In Windows, this can be done with Snappy. I imagine in Linux you probably can configure a window-manager to do that, not having to rely on some desktop software.

Comment: What kind of virtual session is it? Is there a window for the virtual session in the main desktop of the host operating system, and PrintScreen will print the whole desktop? In that case, maybe **Alt + PrintScreen** when that window is focused should make a screenshot of it (in the host operating system). If not, please describe the scenario with more details.

Comment: @sudodus the virtual session is a 3000x40000 pixel huge window - it was virtual preciously because the current monitor can't get a hold of it. So capturing the viewport isn't useful. Sorry I didn't give the entire scenario to prevent TLDR.

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide a direct answer but I solved the problem through my discipline.

Instead of taking a screenshot at every mouse click, do a keyboard combination to run a screenshot capturing software before every mouse click. This requires some discipline from the user, but after working on it for an hour I gained the capacity of habitually do a keyboard combination before clicking.

The virtual session I am running is with this:

```
$ vnc4server # Google search for how to connect to the virtual session.
```

The window manager I used was ratpoison (not the best available, just the one I happen to have). The configuration for the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl+t F1</kbd> is this:

```
$ cat .ratpoisonrc 
bind F1 exec xwd -root -out /tmp/"`date +'%T.%3N'`"
```

The additional parameter after `date` is needed because sometimes two screenshots have to be captured in one second, requiring finer filenames. The output file needs to be processed with `xwdtopnm` later, but the advantage is that the screenshot is taken instantly - other software sometimes captures the screenshot in 0.1 seconds delay, at which time the mouse button might already be clicked.